# how to check booking period is over from current date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, performance

I'm having trouble to determine whether booking period is over or not?

i have 2 `unix timestamp`  like this **start** =>`2017-06-20 12:00:00` and **End** => `2017-06-23 12:00:00`

on each time the `query` is run i want to check whether time is elapsed or not (i,e booking period is reached or not) from my current `date` (which i can pass using `php`)

**my pseudo code:**

```
    select timestampdiff(DAY, '2017-06-20 12:00:00', '2017-06-23 12:00:00'); returns 3

   returnedDate = 3; // returns difference either in date format or no.of days

if((returnedDate - mycurrentDate) == 0){


        //your booking period is over  

}else{


   // no of remaining days
```

}

**Desired Solution**: i'm looking for `mysql` specific solution, good `php` solution is also welcomed.

**Question**: how to know the pre-booking date is expired?

please help me to solve this, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: just use the in between checking in mysql `>= start` and `<= end`

Comment: please help me  by your solution, still i'm looking for solution

Comment: Where/how is `mycurrentDate` determined? is it always `NOW()`, or a date/unix timestamp, or an integer day limit value stored in the database?

Comment: Those aren't timestamps. They're MySQL `datetime` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `mycurrentDate` is `NOW()`, `start` and `end` are the dates in which the event occurs, and the threshold for booking is the `end` date.

You could use `DATEDIFF` to determine the number of days remaining until the event ends and check if the end date has already passed for the event to show 0.

EG: How many days until the event(s) ends

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95b548/2

Assuming `NOW()` is `2017-06-21 12:00:00` using a past, current, and a future events.

```
| id | start               | end                 |
|----|---------------------|---------------------|
| 1  | 2017-06-20T12:00:00 | 2017-06-23T12:00:00 | #current
| 2  | 2017-06-01T12:00:00 | 2017-06-03T12:00:00 | #past
| 3  | 2017-07-01T12:00:00 | 2017-07-03T12:00:00 | #future
```

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    NOW() AS `current_date`,
    `tn`.`start` AS `starts_on`,
    `tn`.`end` AS `ends_on`,
    IF(`tn`.`end` >= NOW(),
         DATEDIFF(`tn`.`end`, NOW()), #show days until event ends
         0 #the event has already passed
    ) AS `days_remaining`

FROM `table_name` AS `tn`
```

Results:

```
| id |        current_date |                  start |                    end | days_remaining |
|----|---------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------|
|  1 | 2017-06-21T12:00:00 | June, 20 2017 12:00:00 | June, 23 2017 12:00:00 |              2 |
|  2 | 2017-06-21T12:00:00 | June, 01 2017 12:00:00 | June, 03 2017 12:00:00 |              0 |
|  3 | 2017-06-21T12:00:00 | July, 01 2017 12:00:00 | July, 03 2017 12:00:00 |             12 |
```

If `end` is stored as a unix timestamp, you can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert it to a DATETIME value:

```
IF(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tn`.`end`) >= NOW(),
     DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tn`.`end`), NOW()),
     0
) AS `days_remaining`
```

Comment: Simpler for `days_remaining`:  `GREATEST(DATEDIFF(..., now()), 0)`.